# SSDT Visual Studio 2013: Config file will not save

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, configuration-files

I created an SSIS package using Business Intelligence studio and since then have been given a new laptop on which I installed Visual Studio 2013. I also installed SSDT and converted this SSIS package.

We use config files as part of our deployment model.

I am now in the need adding DefaultBufferMaxRows and DefaultBufferSize as configurable properties. Everything looks fine until I click on Finish: the dtsconfig file is not updated and remains the same, although I receive a message confirming it was updated.

I am running as an administrator and I have full right on the folder where I try to save the config file. The Package Configuration Wizard has no issues retrieving the existing properties either.

Is this a common issue? What would be a good workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this under source control? Perhaps something like TFS is holding a lock on the existing config file

Comment: Yes, it is a TFS project, but the config file is saved in a local drive.